# compare mysql tables structure (field order)

Tags: mysql

I need to migrate data from one database to another. both databases have the same tables, with the same table name and all contains the same fields, but some fields are in different order than the others. which makes it impossible to use the statement,

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
```

**EXAMPLE for two tables having different orders in fields**

```
[**products** on proudction server] [**products** on testing server] 
products_id,                  products_id,
products_name,                products_cost,
products_cost,                products_image,
products_price,               products_name,
products_image                products_price
```

is there a way to compare two tables and find out the tables that are having fields in different orders?

Answer (score 0):

Try this add column name with query. Document http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

```
INSERT INTO table1 
(products_id,products_name,products_cost,products_price,products_image)
SELECT products_id,products_name,products_cost,products_price,products_image
 FROM table2;
```

Comment: the problem is that I have about 100 tables to be migrated. if I write columns names in the statement to all tables, which I did to some of the tables that I already know having different order in fields, it gonna take really long time. I made a script to generate statement    INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2, and I only want to use your suggestion to the tables not having the same fields order. and thats why I would like to find out those tables first.

Comment: I did it in a hard way. wrote a script to generate the mysql query as you suggested to all tables. and managed to migrate all data to another database. thanks for your hint.